# Create dynamic views while scrolling in view like in Instagram

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, layout

I'm using Retrofit2 to handle http comunication with backend. In response I'm getting data that i wish add to number of views specified in JSON file (size of array).

I want to create views like this but not the same. Basically picture and some text
[image]

I don't know what type of layout i should use. Grid, Relative, Linear, List? I also want to scroll this views.

Comment: Create cardView for showing each data as cards, and when new data is fetched,just update the adapter.

Comment: Nothing but i'm open for propositions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should maybe use recyclerview with cardview items.

You can set a scroll listener to the recyclerview , to define when you want to upload some new data .

Comment: Thanks i will try it